# React Native Firebase: Check if module installed

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

Is there any way I can pre-check if the module, example notification, is configured in Native side?

For example, I call `firebase.notification()` it cause app crash. I'd to check before calling the `notification()` function.

** I am using "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6";

---- Added -----

I am using codepush to do hot deployment.

The issue is that, my **Android** app **v1.0** doesn't have notification configured in native side (android) namely without `new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage()`.

The new native update **v1.1** I added `new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage()` to native code.

By calling `firebase.notification()`, app v1.0 crashed while v1.1 works.

I understand that checking app version can prevent this issue, but I need a direct solution to make sure `RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage` is integrated at native side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use notificaiton like this:

```
firebase.notifications()
```

If you want to pre check if firebase exist, you may do like this:

```
if (typeof firebase !== 'undefined) {
```

Comment: checking `if (typeof firebase !== 'undefined) {` is fine, but how I check this `firebase.notifications`?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem you had but in my case it was a difference between Android and iOS versions.

The solution that worked for me was wrapping the firebase call inside a try/catch block to avoid the crash.